# Marker Google Map Top of view

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I can set marker by `z index` to top of maker but **Google** say click is not passed down to the markers or other overlays with lower `z-index` values.

Have any solution to show marker on top of all marker and can click near marker.
If not have other solution. i will tell my team.

Comment: Can you please share what you ve done so far, no one wants to do it for yoy. And then Did you tried to put clickable of marker to true- after that u can put onClick listener

Comment: if marker is not near. i can click another marker but if marker is near i can not click near marker. i think because of z-index.

Comment: no it is not, all markers, should be on the same level as prioritizing one marker to another kills ux. My advice is to zoom in to increase distance between markers

Comment: but if i'm not set z-index. i can click near marker or far marker. but marker is not top. because when i click marker. i will change icon marker.

Comment: can you please share video, gif or photo of what the problem is. because I am afraid to give wrong answer or out of topic

Comment: that your idea i did that last week. but my senior don't want zoom. i'm sad. if not have solution i wll try to explain my senior.

Comment: no. you speak correct. if i zoom in marker. it can click another marker

Comment: Sorry I didnt catch any of your words, my appologies